# Windows 10 “Remote Desktop Connection has stopped working.”

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10

Since upgrading to Windows 10, the remote desktop client has been intermittently failing with “Remote Desktop Connection has stopped working.” Again it’s intermittent, and sometimes when I re-open and attempt to reconnect it goes through fine. It’s quite annoying.

The following are in the application logs in event viewer. I can't find anything about `LogonDemo64.dll`.

This happens when I try to connect via RDP to Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows 2008, Windows 2012…  And it's intermittent on all of them.

```
Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3878
Faulting module name: LogonDemo64.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5552511b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000002613
Faulting process id: 0x5010
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0f42240478571
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogonDemo64.dll
Report Id: b9c5b2c6-1c67-4f68-8151-34826370ce75
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Faulting module name: LogonDemo64.dll
```

this shows you the cause. The crash is caused by `LogonDemo64.dll`. Go to system32 folder, look for the file version and product name and try to get an update.

Comment: Yeah, tried that.  No clue what uses it...

Comment: search in the registry for the DLL.Do you see a company name? Also try to rename the file and look if it still get loaded my mstsc.exe.

Comment: Thanks MagicAndre, it was a remnant from a credential provider that was installed on my machine as a demo.  #derp

Comment: what was the name of the Provider? Maybe others also need this information?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the faulting module was `vorbis.acm`. It was present in my system because I have ImageLine FL Studio installed. To fix:

1. Rename or remove the `vorbis.acm` file in `System32` folder.
2. Turn off transmission of sound in your remote connection advance settings (I did that)

EDIT: Found a whole article about that in the net: https://tommynation.com/fix-remote-desktop-connection-stopped-working-error/

**From the article:**

The Application log in the Windows Event Log showed the error was related to the remote audio functionality.

Apparently, Remote Desktop Connection is using the Ogg Vorbis ACM codec for remote audio, and this was related to the crash on my local Remote Desktop Connection client.

```
Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 10.0.10049.0
Faulting module name: vorbis.acm, version: 0.0.3.6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001f4f
Faulting process id: 0x2478
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\vorbis.acm
```

Either disable remote audio or rename vorbis.acm in C:\Windows\System32 will fix the issue on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Please quote all relevant information from your url, cite the important stuff, only leaving the link as a reference.

Comment: Updated to add relevant information from the cited web page -- have been having this issue intermittently.  My system marks the end of trading with a bell sound, and at that exact instant my client froze.  I don't have the vorbis.acm, but disabled audio and should be good.